# Transparency key messing up on transparent images

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, transparency

I have a C# WinForm that has a transparent key of Lime. I also set the background color of the form to Lime. This works great for things like buttons and almost anything you can think of. The form looks like it is not there and allows me to create a custom looking form.

I have a picture box with background of Transparent and the picture box image is has a drop shadow. When I run the application, the drop shadow is not transparent. The drow shadow has a background color of the forms background color (lime). It looks horrible.

How do I have a transparent form that also allows transparent images to be placed on it properly.

Programs such as SWTOR game launcher have this nice background drop shadow so I know it is possible.

Thank You!

Comment: Don't expect SO users to install a game launcher so they can answer your question.  Document your question better, at least a screenshot is required.

Comment: SWTOR was only an example he gave for irregular window regions, what he is looking for is in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for one of two things, either [Windows Regions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145207%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
OR
[Layered Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx)

Here is an [excellent example](http://www.vcskicks.com/custom_shape_form_region.php) for C#

Or a little example i put together:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
        Region r;
        PointF[] p = new PointF[9];
        p[0] = new PointF(70, 0);
        p[1] = new PointF(170, 0);
        p[2] = new PointF(240, 70);
        p[3] = new PointF(240, 170);
        p[4] = new PointF(170, 240);
        p[5] = new PointF(70, 240);
        p[6] = new PointF(0, 170);
        p[7] = new PointF(0, 70);
        p[8] = new PointF(70, 0);
        gp.AddPolygon(p);

        r = new Region(gp);
        this.Region = r;

        gp.Dispose();
        r.Dispose();
    }
```

you will need to put this code into the form you want it to effect.

Comment: This does nothing when tested

Comment: how did you test it? works perfectly for me. Do you know how to use `OnPaint`? should i extend the example?